# Showing that $|f~'(0)|+|f~'(a)| \leq am$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f~''$ is continuous in the interval $[0,a]$ and $|f~''(x)| \leq m ~\forall~x \in [0,a].$ Assume that $f$ takes on it's largest value at an interior point of this interval. Show that $|f~'(0)|+|f~'(a)| \leq am$.

**Attempt**: Since, $f$ takes it's largest value at an interior point $c \in [a,b]$

$ \implies f~'(c)=0 , f~''(c)<0$

The least possible negative value of $f~''(c)=-m$

How do I move ahead with this problem?

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:** Thanks for the answers. I have one query though. What could be the use of specifying the condition that $f~''(x)$ is continuous throughout the given interval?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint

$$f'(0)=f'(c)+f''(\xi_{1})(0-c)=-cf''(\xi_{1})$$
$$f'(a)=f'(c)+f''(\xi_{2})(a-c)=(a-c)f''(\xi_{2})$$
so
$$|f'(0)|+|f'(a)|=c|f''(\xi_{1})|+(a-c)|f''(\xi_{2})|\le cm+(a-c)m=am$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: I have one query though. What could be the use of specifying that $f~''(x)$ is continuous? Thanks

Comment: @Wanderer: In this proof you need $f''$ to be continuous, for MVT. For my proof also you need it for Fundamental theorem of Calculus to hold.

Answer (score 3):

Let $c$ be the interior point with $f'(c)=0$.

Now, $|\int\limits_{0}^cf''|=|f'(c)-f'(0)|=|f'(0)|$.

On the other hand, $|\int\limits_{0}^cf''| \leq \int\limits_{0}^c|f''|\leq mc$.

Now apply the same trict to $\int\limits_{c}^a  f''$